# Hadoop localhost connection failed

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to run the following command:

```
hadoop fs -ls /data
```

It is giving me the following error:

```
Call From elkd02/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

I do not understand what is going wrong. I have checked the /etc/hosts file and it contains following:

```
127.0.0.1        Localhost
127.0.1.1        elkd02
```

How should I resolve the issue?

Comment: Did you read the link in the error? What have you tried from it?

Comment: You can check if Hadoop is listening on that port with `sudo netstat -anlp | grep LISTEN`.

Comment: I ran  the command... It would not show me the port over there...

Comment: @cricket_007: yeah I tried telnet the port. But unable to connect... I tried checked if the localhost is mapped correctly with the IP in /etc/hosts... I even tried changing the IP address to core-site.xml But no luck.

Comment: Okay, then the HDFS service isn't running. The IP mapping is only the first step of diagnosing network issues. You also have to ensure services are running and ports are open on both ends of the connection.

Comment: Hey solved the issued by starting the dfs.. thanks @cricket_007